# .htaccess redirecionar quando indexOf

Tags: php, htaccess

Como redirecionar usuário quando o mesmo tentar acessar uma pasta cuja nela não conter a index?

Ex:

```
www.eu.com/ <-- index OK
www.eu.com/arquivos/ <-- index Of redireciona para página inicial
```

Answer (score 0):

### Resolvi assim!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.html !-f

RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%/ [L,R=301]
```